# SmartSVN external graph plugin

Tags: smartsvn

Is there an external graph plugin for SmartSVN fro Windows?
I'm searching for this because I found that SmartSVN is 32 bit only and it wants a 32 bit JVM. So I can't exceed 1500MB of memory heap and I can't set less than 1200MB of memory on smartsvn.vmoptions because the program would not start. The problem is, when I do the graph of a large file this problem comes out:

[image: Error image]

So, is there any solution for this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: The error dialog looks somewhat strange. I'd recommend to contact SmartSVN support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SmartSVN does not provide an interface for external graph plugins.